# How to provide Picker a default "Please select..." option?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'd like to make my Picker to show a "default option" on startup. That means: something like "Please select an option".

I've tried to add a option manually with this phrase, but, this way the "default option" can be re-selected after selecting other options, like it was one of the real options. There is some way to do this?

```
<View style={Styles.row}>
            <Picker
                selectedValue={this.state.initialOption}
                onValueChange={this.handleChangeOption}
                prompt='Options'}
              >
              <Picker.Item label='Please select an option...' value='0' />
              <Picker.Item label='option 1' value='1' />
              <Picker.Item label='option 2' value='2' />
            </Picker>
</View>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can add a conditional to your handleChangeOption so that it would only set state when the value is not 0 (the `Please select an option...` Picker). Something like:

```
handleChangeOption(val) {
  if (val !== 0) {
    this.setState({selectedValue: val});
  }
}

...
  
 <View style={Styles.row}>
    <Picker
       selectedValue={this.state.selectedValue}
       onValueChange={this.handleChangeOption}
       prompt='Options'}
       >
       <Picker.Item label='Please select an option...' value='0' />
       <Picker.Item label='option 1' value='1' />
       <Picker.Item label='option 2' value='2' />
    </Picker>
</View>
```

Comment: This way, at the first press on the Picker, "Please select an option" would appear like it was a choosable option. I'd like to make it appear just before the user press it. Like a title, not an option itself.

Comment: @Luiz I updated my answer. I think you are looking to not change state when the 'Please select an option' selection is chosen.

Comment: Thanks. Seems like react-native doesn't provide the exact functionality, which would not even show "Please select and option" when the user pops up the Picker. But your solution help's me to workaround this.

Answer (score 10):

Here is how I just achieved it in React Native:

**InputPicker Presentational Component:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, Picker } from 'react-native'

const InputPicker = ({
    style,
    hasError,
    title,
    enabled,
    selectedValue,
    onValueChange,
    items,
    firstItem
}) => {
    if (!items || !Array.isArray(items)) return null

    const { container, errorContainer, errorText, pickerTitle, pickerItem } = styles

    return (
        <View style={[container, (hasError) ? errorContainer : null, style]}>
            <Text style={[pickerTitle, (hasError) ? errorText : null]}>
                {title}
            </Text>

            <Picker
                style={[pickerItem, (hasError) ? errorText : null]}
                selectedValue={selectedValue}
                onValueChange={onValueChange}
                enabled={enabled}>

                <Picker.Item key={'unselectable'} label={firstItem} value={0} />

                {items.map((c) => <Picker.Item key={c.id} label={c.label} value={c.label} />)}
            </Picker>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 0,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    pickerTitle: {
        flex: 1,
        textAlign: 'right'
    },
    pickerItem: {
        flex: 2
    },
    errorContainer: {
        backgroundColor: '#F8DEE0',
        borderColor: '#DD0426',
        borderWidth: 1
    },
    errorText: {
        color: '#DD0426'
    }
})

export { InputPicker }
```

**Parent Container View** (using Formik form handler)

```
<CardSection style={{ flex: 0, alignItems: 'center' }}>
    <InputPicker
        title="City"
        enabled
        hasError={touched.person_city && errors.person_city}
        selectedValue={this.props.person_city}
        onValueChange={(value) => {
            this.props.setFieldValue('person_city', value)
            this.props.updateField({ prop: 'person_city', value })
        }}
        items={this.getCities()}
        firstItem="Select your city"
    />
</CardSection>
```

**Parent Container** *this.getCities()*

```
getCities() {
    const cities = [
        { id: 0, label: 'Nanaimo' },
        { id: 1, label: 'Victoria' },
        { id: 2, label: 'Ladysmith' }
    ]
    return cities
}
```

It works because it sets value to 0 if "Select your city" is picked, which makes it a falsy value which triggers `touched.person_city && errors.person_city` and puts it into an error state.

Answer (score 0):

Just in the default class try to add default value that you want to display.

Example :

```
this.state = {         
        type: "House",          
    };
```

in your render:

```
<Picker
    selectedValue={this.state.type}
  >
    <Picker.Item label="House" value="House" />
    <Picker.Item label="Apartment" value="Apartment" />
    <Picker.Item label="Commercial Space" value="Commercial Space" />
  </Picker>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [Yo Wakita's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42169365/10938383) you can set `enabled={false}` this way the user sees the placeholder option as disabled.

```
   <Picker.Item label='Please select an option...' value='0' enabled={false}/>
```